# Getting value of radio button in Post request

Tags: javascript, ejs

I'm trying to write a program that take two pieces of information, a name and a radio button value. I cannot seem to grab the actual value of the radio button in the post request. The ejs page keeps displaying "no sign" and console logs as undefined even when i check the radio button with a value of 1. Any help would be fantastic.

```
theApp.post('/sendUserData', function(req, res) {

    var name = req.body.first;

    var radioButtonVal = req.query.imagePick;

    console.log(name);
    console.log(radioButtonVal);

    res.render('template.ejs', {theName: name, theSign: radioButtonVal});
});
```

```
<body>
<h1>Hi <%= theName %> </h1>

<h1> sign:
<% if (theSign == "1") { %>
        Aries
    <% } else if (theSign == "2") { %>
        Taurus
    <% } else { %>
        No Sign
    <% } %>
    </h1>
</body>
```

```
<h2 id="title">astrology reading</h2><br/>

    <form name="Input" method="POST" action="/sendUserData">
          your First Name: <input name="first" type="text">
      <br/><br/><br/>
      your star sign: <br/>    
      <div class="container">
            <input name="imagePick" value="1" type="radio" id="one">
            <label for="one">
                <img src="images/aries.png" alt="aries" height="150" width="auto">
            </label>

            <input name="imagePick" value="2" type="radio" id="two">
            <label for="two">
                <img src="images/taurus.png" alt="taurus" height="150" width="auto">
            </label>
        </div>

            <input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Save">

    </form>
```

Comment: Could you please post the HTML of your form? Or what `req` looks like? Thank you.

Comment: just added the html!

Comment: change `req.query.imagePick;` to `req.body.imagePick;`

Comment: that worked! thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you should request radioButtonVal from body, not from query.
Try the snippet below and it should work:

```
theApp.post('/sendUserData', function(req, res) {

    var name = req.body.first;

    var radioButtonVal = req.body.imagePick;

    console.log(name);
    console.log(radioButtonVal);

    res.render('template.ejs', {theName: name, theSign: radioButtonVal});
});
```